# generate numbers with "zeros" with a specific templete

Tags: python

I need to generate a csv data file, for that I want to generate a sequence of numbers like this:

```
0000001
0000002
.
.
.
1000000
```

Comment: can you try `nums = [str(i).zfill(6) for i in range(1,1000001)]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
with open('csvfile.csv','w') as file:
    for a in range (1000000):
        file.write("{:06d}".format(a))
        file.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
with open('data.csv', 'w') as f:
    for value in range(1, 1000001):
        f.write('{0:06d}\n'.format(i))
```

The `'{0:06d}'` format specifier indicates to print with 6 digits, and pad with leading zeros if needed. There are a number of similar formatting methods in python with slightly varying syntax.